# From MultiIndex to MultiColumn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas in Python, I want to set a MultiColumn using values from an existing column. I know how to set it as a MultiIndex using `'set_index(['date', 'name'])'` but I don't know how to set it as a MultiColumn.

**Example:**

Suppose I have a df:

```
       name  age  language
date
2000   jack  5    dutch 
2001   jack  6    dutch
2002   jack  7    dutch
...
2000   ben   20   english
2001   ben   21   english
2002   ben   22   english
```

which I want to transform into:

```
name    jack              ben 
        age  language     age  language      
date
2000    5    dutch        20   english
2001    6    dutch        21   english
2002    7    dutch        22   english
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `stack` and `unstack` to solve this:

```
In[2] : df.set_index(['date','name']).stack().unstack([1,2])
Out[2]: 
name    jack         ben
        age language age    language
date                
2000    5   dutch    20     english
2001    6   dutch    21     english
2002    7   dutch    22     english
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot` and `swaplevel` here:

```
df = df.pivot(columns=['name'], values=['age', 'language'])
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
print(df)

name ben          jack         
     age language  age language
date                           
2000  20  english    5    dutch
2001  21  english    6    dutch
2002  22  english    7    dutch
```